# TensorFlow TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

**Edit: Possible answer at the end of the post**

---

Hi I am trying to convert a LSTM into tflite model and I am running into

> TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable

error. My code worked before with python3.6, however due to using the **TensorFlow-nightly 2.7** version (needed for the LSTM conversion), I have to use python 3.7

Now I am getting a bug and I am wondering if my code was wrong from the getgo or should I open a git ticket.

---

In my code I set up a generator function

```
def my_batch_generator(X, batch_size = 500):
    indices = np.arange(len(X)) 
    batch=[]
    while True:
            for i in indices:
                batch.append(i)
                if len(batch)==batch_size:
                    yield X[batch]
                    batch=[]
```

the data input X is read in from an csv file.

```
data=pd.read_csv('./test_x_data_OOP3.csv', index_col=[0])
data=np.array(data)
data=reshape_for_Lstm(data)  #a function that just transforms the array
```

and later I call the generator for the representative dataset:

```
converter.representative_dataset = my_batch_generator(data)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]
converter._experimental_lower_tensor_list_ops = False
quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

and the error is thrown for this line (long traceback, which I will keep for my git ticket :-) )

```
converter.representative_dataset = my_batch_generator(data)
```

**Question: Do you see any mistake in my generator function and how I call it ?** Or is likely it due to using python 3.7?

thanks

---

**edit:**

[Thierry Lathuille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/550094/thierry-lathuille), you are right. I will add the traceback. I will also upload a working code example. However, I made sure not to have my function overwritten as you hint.

You can find a simple version here with the info to download model and csv file.
https://github.com/JanderHungrige/forstackoverflow

**the traceback**

```
  File "/home/base/Documents/Git/KundenProjekte2021/Ginko/pump_sensor/Quantizing_LSTM_3.py", line 59, in <module>
    quantized_tflite_model = converter.convert()

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 775, in wrapper
    return self._convert_and_export_metrics(convert_func, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 761, in _convert_and_export_metrics
    result = convert_func(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 1044, in convert
    result, quant_mode, quant_io=self.experimental_new_quantizer)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 226, in wrapper
    raise error from None  # Re-throws the exception.

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 216, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 722, in _optimize_tflite_model
    model, q_in_type, q_out_type, q_activations_type, q_allow_float)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/lite.py", line 530, in _quantize
    self.representative_dataset.input_gen)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 226, in wrapper
    raise error from None  # Re-throws the exception.

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/convert_phase.py", line 216, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/calibrator.py", line 228, in calibrate
    self._feed_tensors(dataset_gen, resize_input=True)

  File "/home/base/anaconda3/envs/AInight/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/lite/python/optimize/calibrator.py", line 97, in _feed_tensors
    for sample in dataset_gen():

TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable
```

---

**My ANSWER**

It seems there are two ways of solving this.

first is quite simple, just call the function batch_generator without any passing values. The X and batch size is acquired in the function and not passed (How the `batch_generator()` function knows `data` and `batch_size` is not really clear for me). So just like this:

```
def batch_generator():
    for X in data:
        batch_size = 2
        indices = np.arange(len(X)) 
        batch=[]
        while True:
                for i in indices:
                    batch.append(i)
                    if len(batch)==batch_size:
                        yield X[batch]
                        batch=[]

data=pd.read_csv('./test_x_data_OOP3.csv', index_col=[0])
data=np.array(data)
data=reshape_for_Lstm(data) 

converter.representative_dataset = batch_generator
```

The second more elegant way proposed by [joanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216427/joanis) is to create a class object with init and call and then just initialize the generator. Like following:

```
class BatchGenerator():
    def __init__(self, X, batch_size):
        self.X=X
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        
    def __call__(self):
        indices = np.arange(len(self.X)) 
        batch=[]
        while True:
                for i in indices:
                    batch.append(i)
                    if len(batch)==self.batch_size:
                        yield self.X[batch]
                        batch=[]       

data=pd.read_csv('./test_x_data_OOP3.csv', index_col=[0])
data=np.array(data)
data=reshape_for_Lstm(data)  

batch_generator=BatchGenerator(data, 2)   

converter.representative_dataset = batch_generator
```

**Thanks for all your input**

Comment: "long traceback, which I will keep for my git ticket " - well, you should really include it in your question, and provide a [mre]. `my_batch_generator` is clearly not what you expect at this point. There might well be something like `my_batch_generator = <something that is a generator, maybe my_batch_generator()>` before in your code.

Comment: I doubt that basic use of generators changed between Python 3.6 and Python 3.7. I suspect that you made some inadvertent change that broke the code which was working in 3.6.

Comment: Can you please format your error traceback as code, in order to preserve its structure?

Comment: The problem probably lies not with the attempt to call `my_batch_generator` but with a downstream attempt to call `my_batch_generator(data)`. If `dataset_gen` in the last line of the traceback is `my_batch_generator(data)` then `dataset_gen()` would throw that error.

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your input. I should have made the post more structured from the beginning. 
@John Coleman: I think I got it. I have to call the generator without the (). Providing the data has to happen in the generator and not while calling the generator. Thanks for starting my brain.

Comment: Based on the stack trace, it looks like `converter.representative_dataset` needs to be a function, which gets called in that `for sample in dataset_gen():` statement. You can probably write a function which returns your generator when called with no arguments.

Comment: You can do this for a callable class: `class my_batch_generator:` with `__init__` saving `X` and `batch_size` in members, and `def __call__(self):` having the body of your existing function, with `self.X` instead of `X` and ditto for `batch_size`.

Comment: Just passing the generator without the `()` won't be quite enough, because it's not going to be called with any arguments, so you have to save those arguments when you create the generator.

Comment: Hi Joanis, thanks for your input. I think I found the solution and will post the answer tomorrow morning (Europe here). Maybe you can have a look. My main brain-block was the problem you mentioned with the data pass to the function/generator. But apparently, it is not needed. I will reconfirm and post it tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. I wish your question got re-opened so your could post it as a proper answer. Anyway, you comment "how the function knows the data is not clear to me": it's quite simply that both `data` and `batch_generator` are in the same module/file, and `data` is visible to `batch_generator` as a module/file global variable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are two ways of solving this.

first is quite simple, just call the function batch_generator without any passing values. The X and batch size is acquired in the function and not passed (How the `batch_generator()` function knows `data` and `batch_size` is not really clear for me). So just like this:

```
def batch_generator():
    for X in data:
        batch_size = 2
        indices = np.arange(len(X)) 
        batch=[]
        while True:
                for i in indices:
                    batch.append(i)
                    if len(batch)==batch_size:
                        yield X[batch]
                        batch=[]

data=pd.read_csv('./test_x_data_OOP3.csv', index_col=[0])
data=np.array(data)
data=reshape_for_Lstm(data) 

converter.representative_dataset = batch_generator
```

The second more elegant way proposed by [joanis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3216427/joanis) is to create a class object with init and call and then just initialize the generator. Like following:

```
class BatchGenerator():
    def __init__(self, X, batch_size):
        self.X=X
        self.batch_size=batch_size
        
    def __call__(self):
        indices = np.arange(len(self.X)) 
        batch=[]
        while True:
                for i in indices:
                    batch.append(i)
                    if len(batch)==self.batch_size:
                        yield self.X[batch]
                        batch=[]       

data=pd.read_csv('./test_x_data_OOP3.csv', index_col=[0])
data=np.array(data)
data=reshape_for_Lstm(data)  

batch_generator=BatchGenerator(data, 2)   

converter.representative_dataset = batch_generator
```

**Thanks for all your input**